# DataGridView missing new-row with empty datasource

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm creating an application which uses a DataGridView to create and modify a local List that will be imported into a system later. It should be editable by the user (clicking and writing in the DGV), and it should also support importing from csv which means I need 2-way sync between DGV and datasource.

I've set  the DGV's DataSource to a `BindingList<Client>` like this:

```
//In my seperate Client class-file
public class Client
{
    private string _name;
    private string _mac;
    private string _status;

    public Client(string pcnavn, string MAC)
    {
        _pcnavn = pcnavn;
        _mac = mac;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
        }
    }

    public string MAC
    {
        get
        {
            return _mac;
        }
        set
        {
            _mac = value;
        }
    }

    public string Status
    {
        get
        {
            return _status;
        }
        set
        {
            _status = value;
        }
    }
}

//In my mainform class

public BindingList<Client> clientDataSource = new BindingList<Client>();

public MainForm()
{
InitializeComponent();
//clienDataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false; //The duplicate columns where fixed by setting DataPropertyName for all columns.
clientDataGridView.DataSource = clientDataSource;
}
```

With this approach, the DGV is generated, but it is empty(only headers), so the user can't add a row by using the DGV. Without DataSource, it displays a blank row like a SQL editor so I can create rows manually in the DGV. How can I show the "new item"-row when linked to an empty data source? All examples I've found uses non-empty datasources.

`AllowUserToAddRows` and `AllowUserToDeleteRows` are set to `true`.

This picture shows my problem. The "first row" is missing when using datasource. It's not possible to add data by typing in the DGV.
[image: DGV]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When looking at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.allowusertoaddrows.aspx), I found this:

> If the DataGridView is bound to data, the user is allowed to add rows if both this property and the data source's **IBindingList.AllowNew** property are set to true.

It seems `BindingList` has this property as `false` by default, so this little trick fixed it:

```
public BindingList<Client> clientDataSource = new BindingList<Client>() { AllowNew = true };
```

Comment: Glad you found the solution.

Comment: Thanks, I set the AllowNew property of de bindingsource in the designer but still didn't work. Until I used the Datasource-property of the bindingSource instead of the one from the datagridview itself to bind the data. That worked.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are missing the [DataPropertyName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.datapropertyname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) setting.

1. First you have to add columns to your data grid. Go to add columns option and add the required columns using the wizard.
2. Secondly you have to edit each column in the wizard mode and set the `DataPropertyName`. Basically for each grid column you have created you need to give the exact bound property name of Client class.

[image]

---

`Displaying Empty Row`

When you bind a empty list to a DGV default row will be removed. If you need to display an empty row then do like this,

```
//Adding a client object to the collection so that an empty row will be inserted to DGV
clientDataSource.Add(new Client());
clientDataGridView.DataSource = clientDataSource;
```

Comment: I actually missed that on one of the columns, but I had it on the rest. So now I don't get duplicate columns when I remove `AutoGenerateColumns`, but I still don't get the first blank row when a datasource is specified. I'll update the question with pictures of the problem :)

Comment: You sir, are genius! One tiny "problem" though. When I've done this, I get a blank line PLUS the "new-row" (with a star) like the top of my picture. In a perfect world, I ONLY want that one. Because if I use your solution, I will need to create custom logic to avoid people pressing the RUN-button when they only have the blank object I created. I know I'm not that good at explaining, but do you follow? :-) Any suggestions?

Comment: @Graimer I couldn't get you, Are you seeing two empty rows now ? And I i didn't get the point you were talking about RUN button.

Comment: I have a RUN-button to start proccessing the client-list(adding them to SCCM). But yes, I had 2 empty rows. One object in the list + the "new-line" row that datagridview shows. Thanks for your help. I'll upvote, but as I found the "perfect" solution my self(see my answer), I'll mark mine as answer. Thanks again! :-)

Answer (score 0):

See config here
[image: See config here]

```
try
{

  int id =Convert.ToInt32( textBox1.Text);
    string query = "SELECT * FROM ngo.inser WHERE ID LIKE '%" + id + "%'";
    command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
    adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);
    table = new DataTable();
    adapter.Fill(table);

    dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

And go to the datagridview edit column setting. In that DATA menu having DataPropertyName change non property  into actual database column name. Then it will show you that column information . If you  have multiple column then set all information like that.